# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/DefaultParameterNameDiscoverer

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am trying to work out my spring hibernate with maven dependencies.

My server is not starting up and throwing this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/DefaultParameterNameDiscoverer
```

I don't know whether it is a problem with my dependencies or with my server. Let me know if anything would be needed from my project. Here are the dependencies I've added in my pom.xml file. I am using maven 4.0.0.

```xml
<properties>
    <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId> 
        <version>${spring.version}</version> 
    </dependency> 

    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>  -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate annotation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.31</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>abc</id>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Is not wise mix Spring versions in one project, you have the **spring-core** module working with 3.0.5 and the rest of modules with 4.0.6.

Comment: yeah.. got it by adding right dependencies.. thanks for ur response

Comment: check the reply how the solution.

Answer (score 22):

Is not wise mix Spring versions in one project.

The error is, you have the `spring-core` module working with `3.0.5` and the rest of modules with `4.0.6`

Comment: This solution worked for me. Make sure you have only one version of Spring.

Comment: I faced a similar issue. To keep in mind that, It is not only the major version difference which causes issue, I had issue between 4.1.0 and 4.2.6 as well.

Answer (score 5):

Already posted ansewers are correct. This issue is caused by conflicts in dependency version. The fastest way in my opinion to resolve those confilcts is to use plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <rules><dependencyConvergence/></rules>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Run it with mvn enforcer:enforce command. You will get a list of conficted dependencies. Check the library that has the lowest version of certain dependency and downgrade others. It is slow precess though so be patient

Answer (score 4):

Resolution to this problem would depend on your pom.xml and what spring library it has. 
Some rejig of the spring jars including and excluding spring jars in maven will resolve this.

```
I added the following to resolve the mongo-db spring-data jar related issue.

<properties>
        <spring.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.data.version>1.6.1.RELEASE</spring.data.version>
        <spring.core.version>4.1.4.RELEASE</spring.core.version>
    </properties>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>   
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.core.version}</version>                           
        </dependency>

            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${mongo.driver.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jongo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jongo</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.data.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

As Manuel Jordan suggested, it is because of the difference in versions. I just got this error and solved it by setting the same version of org.springframework:spring-core in each one of my modules.

My project structure is as follows:

```
projectname
    module1
    module2
    module3
```

I wrote a test under module2:

```
projectname
    module1
    module2
        src
        test
            < my package >/TestClass.java
    module3
```

When I ran this test, I got this error:

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/ErrorCoded
```

After ensuring each module had the same version of the **org.springframework:spring-core** dependency, the test ran.